# C# string conversion to integer and compare

Tags: c#, asp.net

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xtYc.png)

hi im getting this error while converting strings to int

```
string oneamount = "1200.12366";
string twoamount = "121.11";
int x=Int32.Parse(oneamount);
int y = Int32.Parse(twoamount);

      
            if (x > y)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("okay");
            }
```

Error
input string was not in correct format

Comment: First question is do you know what an integer is ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall yes i do

Comment: Is `121.11` an integer / `Int32` ? I can assure you its not, now the next question is what type could it be?

Comment: how this problem can be solved?

Comment: added an answer expounding @MichaelRandall 's comment

Comment: Guess you could try `(int)decimal.Parse(oneamount)`

Comment: @Raju [Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer): _"An integer is colloquially defined as a number that can be written without a fractional component. For example, 21, 4, 0, and -2048 are integers, while 9.75, 5½, and √2 are not."_

Comment: thanks everyone out there for your valuable time.. got solution.........:) :)

Comment: Why do you want to compare integers when you have decimals? Do you want to just compare the non-decimal component? Or do you want to round correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expounding on @MichaelRandall's comment.

Integers are whole number/no decimal place. If you want to compare with decimal, use `double, float, decimal`

you can convert the `string` values into `decimal` for precision purposes

```
string oneamount = "1200.12366";
string twoamount = "121.11";
var x = Convert.ToDecimal(oneamount);
var y = Convert.ToDecimal(twoamount);

      
            if (x > y)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("okay");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try Int32.TryParse function. It converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation succeeded.

[Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1)

Signature is:

```
public static bool TryParse (string s, out int result);
```

Example:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String[] values = { null, "160519", "9432.0", "16,667",
                          "   -322   ", "+4302", "(100);", "01FA" };
      foreach (var value in values)
      {
         int number;

         bool success = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
         if (success)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.",
                               value ?? "<null>");
         }
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Attempted conversion of '<null>' failed.
//       Converted '160519' to 160519.
//       Attempted conversion of '9432.0' failed.
//       Attempted conversion of '16,667' failed.
//       Converted '   -322   ' to -322.
//       Converted '+4302' to 4302.
//       Attempted conversion of '(100);' failed.
//       Attempted conversion of '01FA' failed.
```

Once you have correct value in your integer, then you can compare them to see whether or nor your operation succeeded.

```
string oneamount = "1200.12366";
int oneAmountInt32;
string twoamount = "121.11";
int twoAmountInt32;
Int32.TryParse(oneamount, out oneAmountInt32);
Int32.TryParse(twoamount, out twoAmountInt32);

      
if (oneAmountInt32 > twoAmountInt32)
{
    Console.WriteLine("okay");
}
```